# Checking for an element from a list in another list

Tags: python, list

I'm coding a battleship game and storing the co-ords of ships in 2D arrays, when I generate a ship I need it to check if there is already one in that position using a `UsedTile` List, however, my while loop doesn't work as planned and the new tiles aren't added to the used tile list, I'm not sure why?
Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I've never used Python and uni wants us to use it for a programming languages unit.

```
#Frigate Generation
UpOrDown = random.randint(0, 1)
FrigatePositionX = random.randint(0, 6)
FrigatePositionY = random.randint(0, 9)
FrigateTiles = []
#Checks theres no boat in the current position
while any(x in UsedTiles for x in FrigateTiles):
  if UpOrDown == 0:
    FrigatePositionX = random.randint(0, 6)
    FrigatePositionY = random.randint(0, 9)

    FrigateTiles = [[FrigatePositionX, FrigatePositionY],
                    [FrigatePositionX + 1, FrigatePositionY],
                    [FrigatePositionX + 2, FrigatePositionY],
                    [FrigatePositionX + 3, FrigatePositionY]]
  else:
    FrigatePositionX = random.randint(0, 9)
    FrigatePositionY = random.randint(0, 6)
    FrigateTiles = [[FrigatePositionY, FrigatePositionX],
                    [FrigatePositionY + 1, FrigatePositionX],
                    [FrigatePositionY + 2, FrigatePositionX],
                    [FrigatePositionY + 3, FrigatePositionX]]
```

I've tried changing the location of the while loop, and I've tried removing it completely (which makes the code work, but I end up with boats in tiles where other boats already are). The code runs but when the while loop is included the new tiles aren't added to the usedtile list.

Comment: Bad choice of data structures to start with. Use dicts or sets for scenarios where set intersections are needed, not lists.

Comment: You're generating the random position and orientation *once*, before the `while` loop.  If the resulting tile positions aren't all empty, then they're going to keep on being non-empty forever, because you don't generate new random values.

Comment: I recommend that you step back and describe the algorithm in English. What are the exact steps in your game that you are trying to immplement here? Specifically, what are you trying to do with `while any(x in UsedTiles for x in FrigateTiles):`? Your comment says `#Checks theres no boat in the current position`, but I don't see a variable called `currentPosition` or anything that correlates to that concept. How do you represent the current position in your code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `while` condition will always be `False` on its first evaluation, because `FrigateTiles` is an empty list, and so `any()` will return `False`.

You can fix this in several ways.

One is to extend the `while` condition as follows:

```
while not FrigateTiles or any(x in UsedTiles for x in FrigateTiles):
```